# Which method prefered for row validation after csv import

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i would like to add an csv import for a classified site for the clients. In the moment i do some research which might be the solution with best performance.

One problem is, that i need row to row validation (i know its slow, but i don't see another option for this) e.g. the correct shipping service chosen, some columns can only contain predefinded values etc.

When i use SQL INSERT i can check each time the values by php, which "takes its time" depening on the amount of imported rows.

So i thought to use LOAD DATA INFILE instead, which is way faster. But is there a way to do a row by row check or is the "normal" INSERT better for this intent.

A little side question, is there a need to use LOAD DATA INFILE for max. 10.000 rows and 30 columns?

Thanks in advance

Clemens

Comment: Create a temporary table and use load data infile into that, then do your validataion on that then select into the real table from the temporary table.

Comment: i understand, but when i then validate each row, isnt the performance advantage of LOAD DATA INFILE lost?

Comment: To some degree but I'm sure you will gain performance in the validation i.e. where shipping_service not in (list of valid shipping_services) vs checking on each insert.

Comment: well i use json encoded data in shipping column. I think this is useless when i validate by sql. Not that easy...